alien romulus and the company motives
In Alien Romulus, the Company Science Officer Rook suggested that the company wished to capture the alien because it was a near perfect organism that was the ideal form for space exploration. Why did this change from initially being sought by the Bio-Weapons division? Either an in- or out-universe explanations welcome.

"suggested" implies that Rook doesn't know for sure and is guessing. What exactly did Rook say?

One doesn't exclude another. The fact that Rook was working on creating "improved" workers using Xenomorphs biology doesn't stop the company from trying to acquire aliens as a weapon.

High risk exploration usually is developed by military branches.
